# pimcore 10.6 : Call to undefined method getQuery in class CustomerManagementFrameworkBundle\Model\ActivityList\MySqlActivityList

Tags: pimcore

i am getting below error in pimcore 10.6. can anyone knows the solution, plz share

[image]

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Call to undefined method getQuery in class CustomerManagementFrameworkBundle\Model\ActivityList\MySqlActivityList").

## overwrite activity store to mysql in cmf.yaml file

```
CustomerManagementFrameworkBundle\ActivityStore\ActivityStoreInterface:
    class: CustomerManagementFrameworkBundle\ActivityStore\MySQL
```

Comment: i have replaced by above code but getting same error